# How to dump a digit string with leading zeros, as a valid yaml string in yaml-cpp?

Tags: yaml-cpp

Creating a yaml string with leading zeros is not escaped with quotes in yaml-cpp. So writing the string to a texfile is not a valid yaml-string.`leading_zeros: 00005` is 5 according to the specification yaml 1.2 (Try yourself: http://www.yamllint.com/)

```
YAML::Node node;
node["leading_zeros"] = "00005";
std::cout << YAML::Dump(node)<<std::endl;
// output: leading_zeros: 00005
// instead of:leading_zeros: "00005"
```

How to bring yaml-cpp to escape a string with leading zeros? So that is would not be interpreted as integer from other yaml parser?

Escaping manually does not seem to be the correct answer.

```
node["leading_zeros"] = "\"00005\"";
```

Update:
The digit value is stored in  a YAML::Node! I am pretty sure it is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

After some time spent on analyzing code I went to this hacky solution: https://github.com/nikich340/yaml-cpp/commit/468e0832b39c8320faa7c925708b76f6a3b1b840
It will save double quotes (or you can change emitte manip to single quotes) around all scalars which were strings with quotes originally.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `YAML::Emitter` directly:

```
YAML::Emitter out;
out << YAML::BeginMap;
out << YAML::Key << "leading_zeroes" << YAML::Value;
out << YAML::Value << YAML::DoubleQuoted << "00005";
out << YAML::EndMap;
```

Comment: That is not a useful real life solution. yaml-cpp's YAML::Node is already used in our SW. So all other values in the same node should not be in quotes, besides the digit string. I am quiet sure it is a bug in yaml-cpp. Please try yourself in any validator available: 00005 is not a string in yaml.