# How can I write a version string as a literal (not string) in YAML-CPP?

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

I am trying to write the following information:

```
hints:
  SoftwareRequirement:
    packages:
      ApplicationName:
        version: [ 1.7.3.nonRelease ]
```

I am using the following section of code:

```
std::string m_exeName = # I get this from my CMakeLists file
std::string versionID = # I get this from my CMakeLists file

YAML::Node hints = config["hints"];
config["hints"]["SoftwareRequirement"]["packages"][m_exeName]["version"] = "[ " + versionID + " ]";
```

And it gets me the following:

```
hints:
  SoftwareRequirement:
    packages:
      ApplicationName:
        version: "[ 1.7.3.nonRelease ]"
```

Is there any way to get the quotes inside the square bracket or remove them entirely? This is to be in line with the [Common Workflow Language](https://www.commonwl.org/) (CWL) standard.

Possibly related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54820610/how-to-dump-a-digit-string-with-leading-zeros-as-a-valid-yaml-string-in-yaml-cp).

EDIT (added results from answer):

Went with this:

```
config["hints"]["SoftwareRequirement"]["packages"][m_exeName]["version"][0] = versionID
```

Result:

```
hints:
  SoftwareRequirement:
    packages:
      ApplicationName:
        version: 
          - 1.7.3.nonRelease
```

With is a valid CWL.

Comment: "Is there any way to get the quotes inside the square bracket or remove them entirely?" - Of course there is. Parse the string and extract the information you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[]` are YAML syntax for a sequence; so if you're trying to write

```
[ 1.7.3.nonRelease ]
```

then you're trying to write a sequence with a single element `1.7.3.nonRelease`. When you tell yaml-cpp to write the string `[ 1.7.3.nonRelease ]`, it notices that if it just pasted the text directly, it would be interpreted as a list, so it quotes the string to prevent that.

If you *really* want to write a list with one element, then make it so:

```
config["hints"]["SoftwareRequirement"]["packages"][m_exeName]["version"][0] = versionID;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Unfortunately, the result wasn't what I was hoping (see my updated question). Cheers!

Comment: Actually, this is valid! Accepted as answer.